# KeyError when cleaning tweets column using stop words in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize, stop-words

I have a data frame of tweets and I'm trying to clean my 'tweet' column- remove stop words and use lemmatization.

Below is my code:

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemmatizer= WordNetLemmatizer()

sentence = df['tweet'].apply(nltk.sent_tokenize)

 0 [ 'country year happy']
 1 [ 'wish happy year']
 2 [ 'live year together']

for i in range(len(sentence)): 
    words=nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence[i]))
    words=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in 
          set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    sentence[i]=' '.join(words)
```

The code above gives me the following error: (I included all the traceback)

```
 KeyError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-384-f4bb836363e1> in <module>
  1 for i in range(len(sentence)):
----> 2     words=nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence[i]))
  3     words=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in 
      set(stopwords.words('english'))]
  4     sentence[i]=' '.join(words)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   870         try:
   --> 871     result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   872 
   873             if not is_scalar(result):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, 
  series, key)
  4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
  4404         try:
  -> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, 
  tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  4406         except KeyError as e1:
  4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or 
  self.is_boolean()):

  pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

  pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

  pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

  pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

  pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
  pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

  KeyError: 34
```

How can I fix the error?

Also, how can I get the result in my data frame- add another column with the results?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sentence.iloc[i]` instead of `sentence[i]`.

## Explanation

The `KeyError` means that there's no `34` in `df.index`.

`sentence` is a Pandas Series; when you access `sentence[i]`, Pandas will first try to use index-based indexing (`df.loc`), but will fall back to location-based indexing (`df.iloc`) if your index is non-numeric.  So this code might work if your index happens to be non-numeric, but otherwise it's not doing what you expect.  You can fix this error by explicitly using location-based indexing (`df.iloc`).

For a self-contained example:

### Doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [10,20], 'tweets': [['hello world'],['foo bar']]}).set_index('index')
sentence = df['tweets']

for i in range(len(sentence)):
    print(sentence[i])
```

### Works

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [10,20], 'tweets': [['hello world'],['foo bar']]}).set_index('index')
sentence = df['tweets']

for i in range(len(sentence)):
    print(sentence.iloc[i])
```

A tip:  Rather than iterating manually through rows in Dataframes, it's usually safer and more performant to write your logic as a function and use `df.apply`.

Comment: The error is solved, but it seems that the loop that I wrote didn't do what I wanted. There are still stop words in the sentence column.

Comment: I think the problem is this part:
`words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in stop_words]`.

It's possible that the un-lemmatized word is not a stop word but it becomes one after lemmatization.

Try adding another `words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]` step.

Comment: Oh, and here's another issue: if you check `nltk.word_tokenize(str(sentence.iloc[i]))`, it's probably not doing what you want either, since you're converting `['hello world']` into `['[', "'hello", 'world', "'", ']']`, which means you've got extra quotes and brackets in there.  What's in your `tweet` lists?  If there's only ever one line you could do `nltk.word_tokenize(sentence.iloc[0][0])`, otherwise you need to iterate through the lists properly rather than turning them into strings.

Comment: Thanks, I added the correction for 'words' (your first comment) and fixed the 'word_tokenize' issue . It still didn't solve the problem. There are stop words in the column and the un-lemmatized words. Do you have another suggestion for this?

Comment: Technically this is a separate question; could you (1) add your new code to your question and (2) show some sample input/output which shows the problem?